# PHP - If select option value equals

Tags: php, jquery, select

I want to comment off `.cities` whenever I select the value `Singaporean` however it should get visible If I choose any other nationality apart from singaporean. Is it possible in PHP ?

```
<div class="cities">New York</div>

<select id="emp_nationality" name='emp_nationality' class='form-control'>
<option  value="Singaporean">Singaporean</option>
<option  value="Albanian">Albanian</option>
<option  value="Algerian">Algerian</option>
<option  value="American">American</option>
</select>
```

I tried this but for some reason it is not working

```
<?php

if ($_POST['emp_nationality'] != 'Singaporean') {
echo '<div class="cities">New York</div>';
}


?>
```

> **ERROR**: Undefined index: emp_nationality

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: emp_nationality means that there is no such variable are there only these options? post more of your code

Comment: can you post code with form tag so that i can review

Comment: <form method='post' id='emp-SaveForm' action="#"> </form>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an onchange handler in js and hide / show the ".cities" div depending on the value chosen. Note I added a display:none to the .cities since your first option in the select list is Singaporean and the function requires a change to trigger it. Also I would normally separate the onclick as a separate handler - rather than mixing it into the HTML but for this example I did it this way. Does not require PHP which would need the option to be selected on page load and would not easily change the visibility of the div on a different choice. This functions to hide the div if the correct option is selected and show it on other option selections.

```js
 function hideDiv(option) 
 {
  if(option=="Singaporean"){$('.cities').hide()}else{$('.cities').show()}
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cities" style="display:none">New York</div>

<select id="emp_nationality" name='emp_nationality' class='form-control' onchange="hideDiv(this.value)">
<option  value="Singaporean">Singaporean</option>
<option  value="Albanian">Albanian</option>
<option  value="Algerian">Algerian</option>
<option  value="American">American</option>
</select>
```

```
<div class="cities" style="display:none">New York</div>

<select id="emp_nationality" name='emp_nationality' class='form-control' onchange="hideDiv(this.value)">
<option  value="Singaporean">Singaporean</option>
<option  value="Albanian">Albanian</option>
<option  value="Algerian">Algerian</option>
<option  value="American">American</option>
</select>


//js
function hideDiv(option)    
{
    if(option=="Singaporean"){$('.cities').hide()}else{$('.cities').show()}
}
```

Comment: Great! This solves my half of the problem. The class citites is my required field and if my hide that my form will not be validated..

Comment: but cities is not an input field and therefore cannot be "required". it is a div. If you need it to be an input field then you need to have it be an input field and then you can set the attribute to disabled which will allow it to be in the form but not used. and incidentally - if as in your OP - you comment it out then it will not be rendered into the page and will not be valid or even present!

Answer (score 0):

If you like would to avoid the "Undefined index: emp_nationality" you need to make sure this variable exists before checking it's value. Use isset( ).
http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

```
if (isset($_POST['emp_nationality']) && ($_POST['emp_nationality'] != 'Singaporean')) {
    echo '<div class="cities">New York</div>';
}
```

Comment: This will display / not display the div on page load, but the problem is that this will not allow the display of the ".cities" if the user chooses a different option after the page load. My understanding of the original problem was that the selection of different options allows the display of the div if the selection is not the "Singaporean" value.